# Notepad++ regex multi passwords?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of usernames as below:

```
John
Michael
Geroge
America
Japan
Motorcycle
```

I want to add to them multi passwords like below:

```
John:123456
John:1234567
John:12345678
Michael:123456
Michael:1234567
Michael:12345678
Geroge:123456
Geroge:1234567
Geroge:12345678
America:123456
America:1234567
America:12345678
```

etc...

Is it possible to do it with regex using notepad++ ?

Thank you,
regards.

Comment: `.*` -> `$0:123456\n$0:1234567\n$0:12345678`?

Comment: What are the rules/specs?

Answer (score 1):

I write this shellscript for join two text files a time ago, and have a format which you want.
Save it how concat, turn it executable, execut ./concat file1 file2.
Result goes to file "out".

```
#!/bin/bash
touch temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4 out
x=temp1
y=temp2
z=temp3
u=temp4
cat $1>$x
cat $2>$z
while [ "$(head -n 1 $x)" ]&&[ "$(head -n 1 $z)" ]
do
    echo $(head -n 1 $x):$(head -n 1 $z) >> out
    sed -e '1d' $x>$y
    sed -e '1d' $z>$u
    if [ $x == temp1 ]
    then
        x=temp2
        y=temp1
        z=temp4
        u=temp3
    else
        x=temp1
        y=temp2
        z=temp3
        u=temp4
    fi
done
rm temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4
```

Comment: This question is about regex and notepad++. Your answer doesn't help at all

Answer (score -1):

I think it was answered but not with details, so try this.

Find what: `.*`
Replace with: `$0:123456\n$0:1234567\n$0:12345678`

Comment: This just repeats the comment made by RamenChef, but without attribution.

Comment: True I have mentioned it in my answer, I just removed slightly parts and prepared it to nodepad++ regex,, as the asker had requested us.